# Why are the outputs different for these 2 sql queries?

Tags: sql, mysql

Two tables:
a) `svn3` with columns `name revno compname`
b) `archdetails` with columns `name version compname inFlat`

Shouldn't these 2 queries output the same result. The output of query 2 is correct. What is wrong with query1?

query1:
`select sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from archdetails inner join svn3 on archdetails.compname=svn3.compname where archdetails.name='ant' AND  version='1.4' AND (revno='r274642' OR revno='r274578' OR revno='r274533')`

query2:
`select sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) from archdetails where name='ant' AND version='1.4' AND compname IN (select compname from svn3 where revno ='r274642' OR revno='r274578' OR revno='r274533')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `svn3` has more than one row with the same `compname` that also have one of the requested `revno` values, then query 1 will count each `svn3` row once. Query 2 will only count each `compname` once. The `IN` clause is eliminating any duplicate `compname` entries in the second query.

If you don't want to count duplicate `compname` entries, then you need to group them in a subquery. One way to do that is using the `IN` clause like you did in query 2. Another option would be to use `GROUP BY` on a subquery, and name that subquery. Then join the named subquery to the `archdetails` table.

If you're trying to solve a performance problem, then I would suggest adding primary keys and foreign keys to the tables. I think that would speed things up.

I've seen some comments that `EXISTS` is sometimes faster than `IN`, but I haven't seen any evidence to back that up. You might want to experiment with that.

Comment: Yeah you are correct. How can I modify query 1 for this? Beacuse query 2 is way too slow even after indexing

Comment: Did you try using query2 but using an 'exists' statement instead of 'in' condition? It is generally far better in terms of performance.

Comment: Thanks, will try using EXISTS.

Comment: @Roopesh, have you found any documentation on why `EXISTS` is faster than `IN`? I've seen a few comments that it is, but not why it is.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlinthewild/archive/2010/03/23/left-outer-join-vs-not-exists.aspx, this is for exists vs join, but even for in the same logic holds. Basically 'in' returns a result set whereas exists returns a boolean condition - so exists does not wait to get all the rows, it returns as soon as the first row in the subquery is returned.

Comment: Sorry, @Roopesh, I don't think that example is applicable. It's for `NOT EXISTS` vs. `LEFT JOIN`. The first entry in that series of articles compares `EXISTS` and `IN` to find that there is no difference: http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/08/17/exists-vs-in/ The article is talking about SQL Server, so there might be differences on MySQL.

Comment: Yes, I agree.. there are cases when there is hardly any difference between exists and in. However a lot depends on data distribution. I have seen many cases where Exists is faster than in, but never seen a case personally where the reverse is true.

Answer (score 2):

No, the two queries are not the same - the first query is joining to svn3 records on compname, for version '1.4' and one of 3 revno values. If multiple svn3 records exist for a given compname (with version '1.4' and any of the 3 revno values), then query1 will return significantly more results.

Possible solution: change

`sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

to

`count(distinct CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN archdetails.compname END)`

(assuming `archdetails.compname` uniquely identifies each archdetails record to be counted in this query, given the other constraints within it.)

Comment: I guess thats what is happening. Any way to correct this using some other form of join or modifying this?

Comment: Thanks, shall check & let you know of the results.

Comment: Thanks, This looks correct for now. Can you please explain this. I have exactly similar query that does select sum(flatFileColSum) instead of sum(CASE WHEN inFlat=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) where flatFileColSum is a column in archdetails. How would I write its equivalent modified sum case?

Answer (score 0):

Having seen other answers, I now think this is an unlikely explanation but will keep it around in case not...

My guess is that this is caused by NULL values somewhere (blame it on the NULL is a tactic that usually works). Are either of `archdetails.compname` or `svn3.compname` nullable and, if so, do either tables contain null values in these columns? If nulls do exist, you need to figure out exactly what you want to happen when nulls are compared.

If it is caused by null values, your [ANSI_NULLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx) setting may also be playing a role here.